# Infinite canvas for taking notes and recording ideas in a freeform way

Tags: windows, osx, software-development

Here's a really useful piece of software I found: https://sketchboard.me (This is *not* an "alternative" question. I thought it might be helpful to use this webapp as an example of the feature set I'm after, which I've defined independently and specifically below.)

Unfortunately, it's only available as a webapp.

I'm looking for something similar that can be downloaded as a program and used offline.

Should save files to disk (i.e. locally and not online.)

Feature requirements:

- Infinite (at least near enough) panning canvas
- Draw freeform lines
- Type text boxes
- Put in images

What would be great:

- Balsamiq-esque wireframes of common tools that can be dragged into positions.
- Colors.
- Arrow tools.
- Zoomable canvas

Answer (score 1):

How about [draw.io](https://www.diagrams.net/)?

- Can be downloaded and used **offline** as an installed- or as a portable program, or can be used online without an account and with saving files locally.
- **Canvas** automatically expands
- You can draw **freehand** lines
- You can import **images**
- Has a huge catalogue of **shapes** and support of custom shapes
- **Colors** (Fill, Line, Text, Gradients, ...)
- Customizable **arrows** between all objects
- **Zoomable** Canvas
- Runs on Windows, Mac and Linux